# Signals between 2 programs

Tags: c, signals

If one program sendS a signal to the second program, can the second program figure out what the pid of the first program is just by the signal sent by it?

First Program: (Code is incomplete, signals is the main focus)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>

void my_handler(int);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(argv[1], "w");

    kill(atol(argv[2]),SIGUSR1);
}
```

Second Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>

void my_handler(int signum){
            if (signum == SIGUSR1)
            {
                    printf("Received SIGUSR1!\n");
            }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int pid;
    pid=getpid();
    printf("PID: %d\n", pid);

    signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);

    pause();
}
```

Is there a way? Or should i put the pid of the first program in `SIGUSR1` somehow and the second program can figure out the pid?

Comment: Sometimes, yes — look up `sigaction()` and look for the extended signal information.

Comment: This is going to be platform specific. What is your target platform? POSIX signals?

Comment: @netcoder ANSI C? Should i post example code?

Comment: @user1763861: If you can post some example code, there is no harm in doing so. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean POSIX signals, then yes. You can access the sender's PID through the `si_pid` member of [`siginfo_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/signal.h.html), though you will need to use `sigaction` and the `SA_SIGINFO` flag to define your handler.

Non-POSIX systems (e.g. Windows) may not even have the concept of a signal (at least not in the POSIX sense), so none of this will apply.

Comment: Non-POSIX C implementations are still required to implement signals. They're just not required to be extended in the same way that POSIX extends them.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Standard C has signals, but they're not (required to be) inter-process, so it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @nneonneo So if i replace signal with sigaction in the signal-catching program I will be able to figure out the PID of whichever process sent a certain signal? or does the program that sends signals need to have sigaction as well?

Comment: @user1763861: The sending program doesn't need `sigaction`. Only the receiving program needs `sigaction`. Remember to put `SA_SIGINFO` in the sigaction structure's `sa_flags`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on a sufficiently POSIX-compatible system, then you can get the information if you set the signal handling with [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html), if you specify a signal handler that takes a `siginfo_t` pointer, and you specify SA_SIGINFO as one of the flags:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static siginfo_t sig_info;
static volatile sig_atomic_t sig_num;
static void *sig_ctxt;

static void catcher(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *vp)
{
    sig_num = signum;
    sig_info = *info;
    sig_ctxt = vp;
}

static void set_handler(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = catcher;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

    if (sigaction(signum, &sa, 0) != 0)
    {
        int errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set signal handler (%d: %s)\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
        exit(1);
    }
}

static void prt_interrupt(FILE *fp)
{
    if (sig_num != 0)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "Signal %d from PID %d\n", sig_info.si_signo, (int)sig_info.si_pid);
        sig_num = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    set_handler(SIGINT);
    pause();
    prt_interrupt(stdout);
    return(0);
}
```

Compile as 'catch' and run:

```
$ ./catch &
[1] 31165
$ kill -2 31165
Signal 2 from PID 26983
$ echo $$
26983
[1]+  Done                    ./catch
$
```

Comment: When I add `sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);` my line that checks if the signal is SIGUSR1 returns false. If i exclude that it says that the pid of the process is 0

Comment: The `sigaction()` page has comments about 'may not work unless signal is between SIGRTMIN and SIGRTMAX'; OTOH, on Mac OS X 10.8.2, SIGRTMIN is not defined at all (but SIGINT works as shown).  YMMV, therefore, and you should study the manual page for your system, as well as the POSIX specification.  Note too that `printf()` is not a function that is deemed safe to call from an interrupt handler.  There are limits on what you can do in a signal handler; standard C is more stringent than POSIX.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a shared memory between the two process.
From the 1st process , obtain the pid using getpid() , and save it to the shared memory area.

```
ShmID   = shmget(PidKey, sizeof(pid_t), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
ShmPTR  = (pid_t *) shmat(ShmID, NULL, 0);
```

In the second process , inside your handler just attach your c program to the shared memory area

```
void my_handler(int signum)
{
 if (signum == SIGUSR1)
 {

  ShmID   = shmget(PidKey, sizeof(pid_t), 0666);
  ShmPTR  = (pid_t *) shmat(ShmID, NULL, 0);
  pid     = *ShmPTR
 }
}
```

At the end of the program , do clean up the shared memory

```
shmdt(ShmPTR);
shmctl(ShmID, IPC_RMID, NULL);
```

Note - The code above is far from complete , no semaphores are used and no other measures are taken against race conditions in a multiprocessor environment.

Comment: each time I get a pid i can store that in some kind of array so i can get the PIDs of all the processes that send signals?

Comment: @user1763861 Yes i don't see why you cant copy the received pid into any array. But the size of the shared memory must be made the size of the array , and you must keep track of the pid pointer , every time you get the SIGUSR sugnal

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure what you mean but the array will be a set size and that size will be the amount of signals that will be recieved.

Comment: @user1763861 say you plan to receive 10 signals and store their pids , create a shared memory area of 10*(sizeof(pid_t)) , and obtain the shared memory pointer , so every time you get a signal , you increment your shared memory pointer , say shmptr++ and store in your pid array, say pis_arr[] , after receiving your 10 pid's just clean up the shared memory and exit